# Why does ReSharper complain about this use of ResourceLoader.GetString?

Tags: c#, localization, resharper, windows-store-apps, embedded-resource

I have a Windows 8 app that I localize as described [in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965329.aspx). My resource files use the default names ("Resources.resw") and locations ("Strings\en-US" etc.).

[image]

When I access the resources via `ResourceLoader`, then ReSharper complains. Example:

```
private readonly ResourceLoader _resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();

private void DoSomething()
{
    string s = _resourceLoader.GetString("TestEntry");
}
```

[image]

ReSharper complains that I'm creating an ambiguous reference, because there are several "TestEntry" keys in several resource files. Duh. That's the whole point. The resource management should automatically use the correct resource, and it does indeed.

So, why does ReSharper complain? Is it a bug in ReSharper or **is** there **really** something wrong?

By the way: ReSharper <strike>recommends (among other fairly useless things)</strike> offers to put `resource:` before the key string, like `_resourceLoader.GetString(resource: "TestEntry")` <strike>(and then complains that it's redundant)</strike>. This makes the ReSharper warning disappear. What does that do? Is it an improvement?

Edit: Oh my! I somehow thought `resource:` is some special syntax, but it's just a [named method argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)...

Comment: `ReSharper recommends...and then complains that it's redundant` I'm starting to think Resharper looks a lot like my girlfriend.

Comment: " ReSharper recommends (among other fairly useless things) to put resource: before the key string" - no. Be careful to distinguish between ReSharper's [Quick Fixes](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Quick-Fixes) and [Context Actions](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Context_Actions)

Comment: @AakashM: Oops. Yes, you are right. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: You may find this post interesting:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527955/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-using-hard-coded-resw-keys-with-the-windows-store-app-re/17527956#17527956

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue with Jetbrains: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Comment: Do you have a "Custom Tool" specified on either of these files ?

Comment: @SaintGerbil This is Windows 8 stuff. No custom tool, but build action PRIResource. Anyway, that is not what his question is about.

Comment: Had the same issue, and opened the actual .resx file (with F7 to see the actual source xml) to investigate, and it seemed that the resource string inside the file was indeed duplicated somehow. So, you might want to check that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of constructing a new ResourceLoader, try using the static GetForCurrentView() method to retrieve the appropriate ResourceLoader.

```
private readonly ResourceLoader _resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();

private void DoSomething()
{
    string s = _resourceLoader.GetString("TestEntry");
}
```